# Add a default sentence while sharing an image on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

Does anyone know how to set a default sentence when the user shares something on his wall? Im not asking about the the user's text. I'm asking how to show the tagline "... took a photo with ...".

[image: took a photo with instagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [this](http://www.getsharekit.com/docs/#image) link.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.jpg"]; // You Image that u want to share
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image title:@"XXX : took a photo with Instagram"];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

Hope it worked for You.

Comment: Thank for your reply . But the result I want should be the "... took a photo with ... " which is just like the link showing http://i.stack.imgur.com/6BEDl.png . Do you know how can I do it ? And also I want to know hot to add a string after the title user edited .